# Why use the indefinite article in "donated a set"

Tags: indefinite-article

Why there is the indefinite article in the following sentence:

> Paramount Studios has donated **a** set from Bluebeards’s Eighth Wife.

I wonder if there is a question to know why we used 'a' and not 'the', because in 'One night I was sitting on the bed in my hotel room on Bunker Hill' we can answer the question 'Which bed' this is the bed in the hotel room of Bunker Hill! Is there a question to justify 'a'?

Comment: Actually, it is *the* bed (there is only one) in *a* hotel room (there are surely at least two rooms in your hotel and there may even be multiple hotels).

Comment: Ok ! Thank you guys ! <3 You really helped & saved me !

Answer (score 2):

Presumably Paramount had more than one set from Bluebeards’s Eighth Wife from which to choose.